# How to translate descriptions in datasets in CKAN??

Tags: babeljs, ckan, transifex

I would like to know how to translate the descriptions and tittles in CKAN.

I have been looking at an example in:

https://opendata.swiss/ and the code in https://github.com/opendata-swiss/ckanext-switzerland

and

https://opentransportdata.swiss

in the extension I see  the files for every language:

https://github.com/opendata-swiss/ckanext-switzerland/tree/master/ckanext/switzerland/i18n

but I can't see the text for every dataset in several languages.

For instance:

https://opendata.swiss/en/dataset/bahnhofsliste-station-list

I think the name of this dataset was created in german, but we get the text in english too.

So the question is:

Where is defined the text for dataset description???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the [multilingual extension](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/multilingual.html).

If you take a closer look at the [metadata](https://opendata.swiss/api/3/action/package_show?id=bahnhofsliste-station-list) of the example dataset you cited then you'll see that the relevant fields (e.g. `description`) are provided for multiple languages.

The `*.po` files in the `i18n` directory are for translating the static parts of the user interface, they are not used for strings that vary from one dataset to another.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give a try. I didn't know it